# Relationship trouble within PowerBI dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, relationship

Please help me if you can.

I created a table (name 'Posicao') within PowerBI with DAX with three columns: 'Deal', 'Month', 'Volume'

At 'Volume' Column I'm using a SWITCH function to access different tables from my model (i.e. Table1, Table2, Table3....)

MY trouble is when I'm at report sector: I'm reading my created table, but whenever I try to put a filter on it (for instance, filtering a city onto 'Table1', values are the same).

Do you know if SWITCH function has a restriction on this type of situation?

Below I share some pics

[image: Created Table with three columns 'Deal' or 'Tipo', 'Month', 'Volume']

[image: Visualization Report: it seems it's working]

[image: When I try to filter per city, for instance, it just does not update]

[image: Relations page: 'Posicao' table is related to all others. 'Cidade' means the city that, in the last picture, I tried to see better.]

Comment: calculated columns can not respond to filters. You need to implement Volume as a measure instead.

Comment: tks for returning, RADO